# How to use API to calculate the data traffic when using Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to know the amount of flowing data in my IoT data platform to see if I can improve the efficiency of the system. Does Apache IoTDB have an api that can count and report the data traffic, that is, the data amount that is transporting in the whole platform?